# opengl frustum culling without glGet* calls

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, lwjgl, frustum

Various examples of view frustum calculations are using glGetFloatv() to get the current projection and modelview matrices (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX), and based of that do some view frustum culling.

I have read that glGet* is something you do not want in your main render loop;

> "Using "Get" or "Is" functions slows
>   down render performance. These
>   commands force the graphic system to
>   execute all queued OpenGL calls before
>   it can answer the "Get" or "Is"
>   query."

So my question is. How do I create a solid Frustum culling algorithm in my code and
where do I put it in order to ensure that this stalling never happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always store the current matrices in your app so that when you want them you don't need to make a glGet call, you can just grab them ...

Answer (score 3):

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/viewfrustum/